# How to stop variable from going back to default value when read in different file

Tags: swift, global-variables

I have a DiscoveredSerialNumbers class that I want to access from various swift files:

```
class DiscoveredSerialNumbers {
    var snConnect: String = ""
}
```

In my ViewController I change the value of snConnect based on the selection from a Picker View.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var SerialNumbers: UIPickerView!

var serialNums: [String] = [String]()
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
...

    SerialNumbers.dataSource = self
    SerialNumbers.delegate = self
}
...
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let global = DiscoveredSerialNumbers()
    global.snConnect = serialNums[row]
    print(serialNums[row])
    print(global.snConnect)
}
}
```

When I print out the new value of snConnect set in the following line:

```
global.snConnect = serialNums[row]
```

Immediately afterward I get the new updated value of snConnect.

However, when I try to access the updated value of snConnect in a different swift file that controls a different ViewController in the following code:

```
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    let global = DiscoveredSerialNumbers()
    var sn = global.snConnect
    ...
}
```

The value of snConnect reverts back to the original value which is "".

How do I stop the value from reverting back to the initial value? I think it has something to do with me initializing the class DiscoveredSerialNumbers but I do not know how to access the value of snConnect in a different swift file otherwise.

Edit: Thanks to Don's comments, I am trying to have the snConnect value persist between instances of the application launching. I want to set the value of snConnect in the main app and access it when I launch an extension to the main app, in this case a custom keyboard extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an app extension to access data stored through it's container app, both the application and extension need to be part of the same app group. App groups are set in Signing & Capabilities section of Xcode for your project.

Once your app and extension are part of the same app group, you can use the following code to set the value of a global variable:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.dataShare")
defaults?.set(serialNums[row], forKey: "snConnect")
```

Where group.dataShare is the name of your App group.

To retrieve the value, you can use the following code in your extension:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.dataShareImada")
var sn = defaults?.string(forKey: "snConnect")
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Question was a bit misleading you actually need to save the variable. I'm not sure if UserDefaults for app and keyboard extension are the same, you can try this.

```swift
class DiscoveredSerialNumbers {

    static var main = DiscoveredSerialNumbers()
    var snConnect: String {
        get {
            // Read from UserDefaults
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "snConnect") ?? ""
        }
        set {
            // Save to UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "snConnect")
        }
    }
    init() {
        print("New instance of DiscoveredSerialNumbers initialized.")
    }
}
```

You can do this with a number of different ways,
however easiest one is creating a singleton of DiscoveredSerialNumbers() object, so your object and values can be used globally through it.

(although this method should be used with caution, it can cause a number of problems)

```swift
class DiscoveredSerialNumbers {

    static var main = DiscoveredSerialNumbers()
    var snConnect: String = ""
    init() {
        print("New instance of DiscoveredSerialNumbers initialized.")
    }
}
```

now whenever you call `DiscoveredSerialNumbers.main.snConnect` old value will be kept and can be used/changed from anywhere.

Edit: Here's a sample Playground code for you to test out how singletons work

```swift
class Singleton
{
    var someVariable = ""
    static var main = Singleton()
}

class ClassA
{
    init() {
        Singleton.main.someVariable = "Hey I was changed in Class A"
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    init() {
        print(Singleton.main.someVariable)
        Singleton.main.someVariable = "And now I'm changed in class B"
    }
}

let _ = ClassA()
let _ = ClassB()
print(Singleton.main.someVariable)
```

Comment: I am still observing the same behavior. I am setting snConnect by DiscoveredSerialNumbers.main.snConnect = serialNums[row] and calling it in a different swift file as DiscoveredSerialNumbers.main.snConnect. Is that correct?

Comment: You should be able to use the modified value from anywhere in the code, can you confirm that you update before you request the variable?(you can add breakpoints and see which one your code hits first, the centralManager one or pickerView) Check my updated code for a simple and quick playground demonstration.

Comment: centralManager is part of a different view controller and different swift file. centralManager is a function inside of a custom keyboard extension to the main view controller file where I set the value of snConnect. So when I set breakpoints at pickerView and centralManager, I only reach one or the other because pickerView is only available in one view controller. However, when I set a breakpoint in centralManager and DiscoveredSerialNumbers, when I try to fetch the value of snConnect, it resets it to the initial value. Isn't that not how singletons are supposed to work?

Comment: The thing is singletons don't "reset", they keep their value (you can copy paste the code I provided in a playground and run it to see how Singleton.main.someVariable keeps it's value between calls from different classes (different files or not, you are accessing the singleton from a different class under a different function, same applies to the example), check the answer I've rewritten your code, please run it and let me know the result it prints to console

Comment: The following gets printed when I added your edited code: New instance of DiscoveredSerialNumbers initialized.
requesting value of snConnect:

Comment: As I said, you are using the value before updating it, compilers aren't magicians, you need to first bring the pickerview, update the value, then later use it.

By the looks of the printed code your "centralManager viewController" runs before you bring up the pickerView, if you want your Singleton value to persist between app launches it's a whole another situation.

Comment: I need the singleton value to press between app launches because the extension gets launched separately from the main app. Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: Oh well, your explanation was a bit misleading, please update your question so it wouldn't be confusing for others either, I will update the answer.